# p:commandButton action not invoked after and ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page which has a p:commandButton which has ajax=true and renders a p:panel which is wrapped in p:outputPanel when clicked. When this button is clicked the action method will set showCreateUser value in ManagedBean to true and this is used to render the Panel. This works fine - on button click the panel is rendered properly. Inside the p:panel there is another p:commandButton. This commanButton is not working as nothing happens when I click on it. The action method is never invoked. When I debug I realised that even though the ajax action sets showCreateUser to true but when I click on second button the showCreateUser value is false. So, the panel panel rendered=false and so the action is never invoked. Following are the xhtml and managedbean class. How can I resolve this? Thanks for your help!

registration.xhtml

```
<h:form id="userForm" style="background-color:white;border:0px; width:90%;">
   <p:messages id="messagesForDebugging"
               showDetail="true"
               autoUpdate="true" />
   <ui:debug hotkey="x"/>
   <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
       <p:commandButton id="btnConfirmYes" value="Yes" ajax="true" update="userRegOutPanel" 
               action="#{regBean.confirmYes}" styleClass="button" style="height:35px;">
        <!-- <f:ajax render="userRegOutPanel" execute="userRegOutPanel"/> -->
       </p:commandButton>

       <p:commandButton id="btnConfirmNo" value="No" ajax="false"
             action="#{regBean.confirmNo}" styleClass="button" style="height:35px;"/>
   </div>

   <p:outputPanel id="userRegOutPanel">
        <p:panel id="userRegPanel" rendered="#{regBean.showCreateUser}">
            <p:panelGrid id="userRegPanelGrid">
                <p:row>
                   <p:column style="width:40%;background-color:#00a5b6;-moz-border-radius: 10px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;-khtml-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;text-align:left;">

                      <h:inputHidden id="ssn" value="#{regBean.ssn}"/>

                      <p:panelGrid>
                          <p:row>
                              <p:column>
                                  <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="true" action="#{regBean.submitRegistration}"                                                 
                                           styleClass="button" style="width:140px;height:35px;" type="submit"/>
                              </p:column>
                          </p:row>
                      </p:panelGrid>
                   </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
   </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Managed Bean

```
    @ManagedBean
        @ViewScoped
        public class RegBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegBean.class);

    private String ssn;

    private boolean showCreateUser = false;

    public void confirmYes(){
        setShowCreateUser(true);
    }

    public String confirmNo(){
        log.info("In retrieveRegistration");
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        fc.addMessage("registrationError", new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "Error. Contact customer service",
                "Error. Contact customer service"));
        return "/registration/registrationError";
    }

    public String submitRegistration() {  
        log.info("In submitRegistration");
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        return "/secured/home";
    }  

    public String getSsn() {
        return ssn;
    }
    public void setSsn(String ssn) {
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }

    public boolean isShowCreateUser() {
        return showCreateUser;
    }

    public void setShowCreateUser(boolean showCreateUser) {
        this.showCreateUser = showCreateUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked. You may relate to one of mistakes stated in the answer by Balusc

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:commandButton id="btnConfirmNo" value="No" ajax="false"
action="#{regBean.ConfirmNo}"
styleClass="button" style="height:35px;"/>
```

In above code ,you've set action to be "`ConfirmNo`". I don't see any method as such.

Change above code as :

```
<p:commandButton id="btnConfirmNo" value="No" ajax="false"
action="#{regBean.agentConfirmNo}"
styleClass="button" style="height:35px;"/>
```

Now, it will invoke the method `agentConfirmNo` from your registration bean.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Makky, there was a typo in my earlier code. I updated it now. I already have to correct methods in xhtml. One more thing to point out is that the Submit button works fine if I don't do any ajax calls in previous calls that render/update the parent components of the submit button.